# How many developers per project are allow in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm working with Google-App-Engine and I have a team of 25 developers, I wonder if I can enroll them all in one project. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Google App Engine doesn't care how your application is developed and by how many persons. It takes an app, and runs it, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific limit for number of participants.